# Как разделить элемент массива, который является строкой на отдельные слова? Javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

**Доброго дня!**

У меня есть некоторая строка, которая содержит в себе несколько предложений текста. Мне нужно возвращать каждое первое слово из каждого предложения.

Я написал функцию, которая разделяет всю строку на предложения. Но допереть как возвращать каждое первое слово из каждого предложения я не могу.

```js
let string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'

function firstWord(text) {
  let formattedText = text.split('. ')
  return formattedText
}

console.log(firstWord(string))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь надо пробежаться циклом по коллекции (formattedText), сделать `split` по пробелам и брать первый элемент новой коллекции. Все эти слова надо помещать в какой-то массив, а потом только вернуть этот массив

Answer (score 0):

Например так получите разбиение по словам

```
formattedText.split(/[\s,.]+/)
```

А так - первое слово, соответственно

```
formattedText.split(/[\s,.]+/)[0]
```

```js
console.log( 'asd,asd ёжик. dasd.ds'.split(/[\s,.]+/) )
```